# How to draw a line with JavaFX

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I have the below code and I am try to create 4 labels with two of them in two VBoxes. I want to connect these VBoxes with a line.

I am not able to find the correct x,y values to place the line in correct position.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    Label  label1  = new Label("Info \n 1");
    label1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    label1.setWrapText(true);

    Label  label2  = new Label("Info 2222222222222");
    label2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    label2.setWrapText(true);

    VBox vbox1 = new VBox(5);
    vbox1.setMaxWidth(50);
    vbox1.getChildren().add(label1);
    vbox1.getChildren().add(label2);

    Label  label3  = new Label("Info \n 3");
    label3.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    label3.setWrapText(true);

    Label  label4  = new Label("Info 444444444444444444");
    label4.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    label4.setWrapText(true);

    VBox vbox2 = new VBox(5);
    vbox2.setMaxWidth(50);
    vbox2.getChildren().add(label3);
    vbox2.getChildren().add(label4);

    HBox hbox = new HBox(100);
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox1, vbox2);

    Bounds bounds = label1.getBoundsInLocal();
    double startX = bounds.getMaxX();
    double startY = (bounds.getMaxY() - bounds.getMinY()) /2;

    Line line = new Line(startX, startY, startX+100, startY);   
    line.setStrokeWidth(5); 
    line.setStroke(Color.BLACK); 

    Pane stack = new Pane();
    stack.getChildren().addAll(hbox, line);

    root.getChildren().addAll(stack);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried using `setTranslateX()` and `setTranslateY()` on the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout bounds are not computed until the first pulse (i.e. until the layout is actually performed). The best way to fix this is with bindings.

Additionally, you are using the local bounds of the label, instead of the bounds relative to the container the line is in. You need to make the appropriate transformation.

I'm not really clear what you are trying to connect, but this example will connect `label1` to `label3`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConnectedVBoxes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Label  label1  = new Label("Info \n 1");
        label1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
        label1.setWrapText(true);

        Label  label2  = new Label("Info 2222222222222");
        label2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
        label2.setWrapText(true);

        VBox vbox1 = new VBox(5);
        vbox1.setMaxWidth(50);
        vbox1.getChildren().add(label1);
        vbox1.getChildren().add(label2);

        Label  label3  = new Label("Info \n 3");
        label3.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
        label3.setWrapText(true);

        Label  label4  = new Label("Info 444444444444444444");
        label4.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;-fx-padding: 10px;");
        label4.setWrapText(true);

        VBox vbox2 = new VBox(5);
        vbox2.setMaxWidth(50);
        vbox2.getChildren().add(label3);
        vbox2.getChildren().add(label4);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(100);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox1, vbox2);


        Line line = new Line();   
        line.setStrokeWidth(5); 
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK); 

        Pane stack = new Pane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(hbox, line);

        ObjectBinding<Bounds> label1InStack = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
            Bounds label1InScene = label1.localToScene(label1.getBoundsInLocal());
            return stack.sceneToLocal(label1InScene);
        }, label1.boundsInLocalProperty(), label1.localToSceneTransformProperty(), stack.localToSceneTransformProperty());

        ObjectBinding<Bounds> label3InStack = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
            Bounds label3InScene = label3.localToScene(label3.getBoundsInLocal());
            return stack.sceneToLocal(label3InScene);
        }, label3.boundsInLocalProperty(), label3.localToSceneTransformProperty(), stack.localToSceneTransformProperty());

        DoubleBinding startX = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> label1InStack.get().getMaxX(), label1InStack);
        DoubleBinding startY = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            Bounds b = label1InStack.get();
            return b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2 ;
        }, label1InStack);

        DoubleBinding endX = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> label3InStack.get().getMinX(), label3InStack);
        DoubleBinding endY = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            Bounds b = label3InStack.get();
            return b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2 ;
        }, label3InStack);

        line.startXProperty().bind(startX);
        line.startYProperty().bind(startY);
        line.endXProperty().bind(endX);
        line.endYProperty().bind(endY);


        root.getChildren().addAll(stack);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

With this technique, even if the labels move when the user resizes the window (or for other reasons), the line stays connecting the labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! That worked..
I have this as part of a larger application, where i wanted to display several linked boxes.. I had just put a sample one here